# How do I get LSAfun to compare two rows of data in R?

Tags: r, nlp, data-science, lsa

I'm a neophyte in R.

I have a data frame that consists of about ~4000 conversations between two people.  It's structured roughly like this:

| Unique Identifier | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | blahblah | blahblah |
| 789412 | blahblah | blahblah |

My goal is to get a similarity score for message 1 and message 2 of each row.  So eventually the data frame would look like:

| Unique Identifier | column1 | column2 | cosine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | blahblah | blahblah | .562 |
| 789412 | blahblah | blahblah | .264 |

Ultimately, I’d have ~4000 scores (one for each row). I’m assuming that costring is the correct command to run for this, but I keep getting errors.  I'm assuming it's because R doesn't know that I want to compare column1 & 2 in each row.

Comment: Please share the error message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

consider the stringdist package instead

```
library(stringdist)

test_data <- tibble( col1 = c("blaahblah", "hello this is a test"),
        col2 = c("blaahblah", "goodbye test"))

test_data %>%
  mutate(cosine =  1 -stringdist(col1, col2, method = "cosine"))
```

We take 1 - the cosine distance to get cosine similarity.

```
  col1                 col2         cosine
  <chr>                <chr>         <dbl>
1 blaahblah            blaahblah     1    
2 hello this is a test goodbye test  0.621
```